# Remove file, but only if it's a symlink

Tags: bash, command-line, rm

Ideally I'd like a command like this

```
rm --only-if-symlink link-to-file
```

because I have burned myself too many times accidentally deleting the file instead of the symlink pointing to the file. This can be especially bad when sudo is involved. Now I do of course do a `ls -al` to make sure it's really a symlink and such but that's vulnerable to operator error (similarly named file, typo, etc) and race conditions (if somebody wanted me to delete a file for some reason). Is there some way to check if a file is a symlink and only delete it if it is in one command?

Comment: I don't think that the race condition should be a concern.  Anybody who would be able to remove the symlink and replace it with a file would need write permission on the directory, which means they could also delete the file themselves.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
 $ rm_if_link(){ [ ! -L "$1" ] || rm -v "$1"; }

 #test
 $ touch nonlink; ln -s link
 $ rm_if_link nonlink
 $ rm_if_link link
   removed 'link'
```

Comment: Surely it would be more clear to remove `!` and change `||` to `&&`

Comment: @glennjackman I've made it a habit to prefer the `||` form. `&&` brings things down if you're in `set -e` mode.

Comment: @PSkocik That's risky in general since it doesn't distinguish between the interesting case (the file exists and is a symlink) and other reasons for a non-zero exit code, such as an empty unquoted value (`[ ! -L $1 ]`), using an invalid operator (`[ ! -l foo ]`), or even syntax error (`[ ! -q foo || echo foo`)

Comment: `-e` isn't a problem since you're using `test`.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov The problem with `rm_if_link(){ [ -L "$1" ] && rm -v "$1"; }` is that running it on a nonlink in `set -e ` mode will kill your shell process. You could append `|| :` but then it becomes, IMHO, even less clearer than the `! ||` version, and it will prevent a `rm` failure from killing you in `set -e`, which is likely undesirable. `! ||` is quite concise and clear, and doesn't suffer from any of these problems.

Comment: [Nope](https://gist.github.com/xiongchiamiov/04d0e1600b040f1a0d97).  Other options: a) put the `rm` inside your test, b) use an actual if statement, c) don't go around using `-e` inside interactive shells (and test your scripts!).  If you want to argue about readability, using `if` to test if something is a link is pretty clearly the winner.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov  It kills all `dash`,`bash`, and `ksh`. `zsh` is the boy who lived, but this question is tagged `bash` not `zsh`.

Comment: `if [ -L "$1" ]; then rm "$1"; fi` is simplest

Answer (score 7):

You can use `find` and its `-type l` test condition (which tests to see if the object found is a **l**ink or not)

For example, if you have a file called `foo` in the current directory, you could do this:

```
$ find . -type l -iname "foo" -delete
```

You might be able to simplify that with just:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -delete
```

Which would delete all symlinks in the current directory.

Warning:

The `-delete` option in `find` is really really dangerous. BE SURE TO PLACE IT AT THE END OF THE FIND COMMAND. If you misplace it, it will delete everything it finds regardless of whether the results match your conditional.

As suggested in the comments, a safer option might be to use `find` and `rm -i` (which forces you to confirm file removal) in conjuction:

```
$ $ find . -type l -iname "foo" | xargs rm -i
```

Personally I use `-exec trash {} \;` to temporarily delete files, because I, like yourself, have been burned by `rm` in the past. Double goes for a misplaced `-delete` flag.

http://slackermedia.ml/trashy

Comment: I worry that this would leave me prone to even more catastrophic user error...

Comment: edited my answer to include a recommendation to not use rm or delete, and to get a good commandline trash tool. Let's face it: if you are removing a file with something without a recovery option, then you're putting yourself at risk.

Comment: Instead of -delete you can just print it and pass it to xargs: `find . -type l -iname "foo" | xargs rm -i`       it's safer.

Comment: I like@BobanP.'s use of ``rm -i`` for safety, for sure.

Comment: "This would delete all symlinks in the current directory" ... and any point below it.

Comment: As @JosephR. said, it will go all the way down the road. Add -maxdepth 1 in find.

Comment: Still breaks on filenames with spaces.  Suggest using `-print0` for `find` and `-0` for `xargs`.

Answer (score 5):

```
zsh -c 'rm foo(@)'
```

`@` is a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers); the pattern `foo(@)` matches what `foo` matches, but only the symbolic links.

`foo(-@)` would only match broken symbolic links. `foo(@,L0)` would match only symbolic links and empty files.

Of course, if you're running zsh in the first place, you just need to type `rm foo(@)`. You do need to take care not to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before typing `(@)`.

Comment: Zsh sounds more and more powerful when I see answers like this.